# What is the time complexity of below geometric series?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

1) ....+n/16+n/8 + n/4+ n/n..=?

2) ...+n/5+n/4 + n/3+n/2...n/n..=?

I am working on finding time complexity of few algorithms where i came across few geometric series.
I believe 1st geometric series has log(n) .What is time complexity of 2nd geometric series?

Comment: How do you get from `n/16 + n/8 + n/4 +...` to `n/n`? Same for the second series. Shouldn't the `n/n` at the beginning or the series listed in reverse?

Comment: just edit my question. the sequences starts  depending on outer loop and gradually ends at n/n i.e 1

Comment: Since this is a sum that sums up elements of *O(n/k)*, this can not be less than *O(n)*, so *O(log n)* is not possible, since the first item of this geometric series is already *O(n)*.

Comment: so if we reduce it it will be n(...1/16+1/8+1/4..+1). So what will be complexity of "...1/16+1/8+1/4..+1"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that (1) is n * (… + 1/2^k + … + 1/16 + 1/8 + 1/4 + 1/2 + 1/1), the answer is 2n because the sum 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + … + 1/2^k + … converges to the value 2. To see this:

```
1/1 + 1/2 + … + 1/2^n + … = k
(1/1 + 1/2 + … + 1/2^n + …)/2 = k/2
1/2 + 1/4 + … + 1/2^(n+1) + … = k/2
k - 1 = k/2
k/2 = 1
k = 2
```

The key step above was recognizing the LHS of the third line is one less than the LHS of the first line.

For (2), n * (… + 1/k + … + 1/5 + 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/1) is n times the harmonic series. The harmonic series diverges so this is undefined, tending toward infinity. To see this, compare the two series:

```
1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 + …
1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + …
```

The second is the same as the first but all terms have had denominators increased to the next higher power of two. Thus the second series cannot sum to a larger value than the first. But the second series clearly diverges since we can group two 1/4s, four 1/8s, etc., to get the sum 1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + … + 1/2 + …

Comment: The harmonic series does diverge if you add up all the terms, but if you add up only the first n of them you get the nth Harmonic number H_n, which is Theta(log n). It's possible (?) that the OP only meant to add n of those terms, so I figured I'd point that out.

Answer (score 1):

1) n{(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+...} ==>O(n) because this series {(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/4)+...} equal to number 2

2) n{(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+(1/4)+...} ==>O(n Lnn) because this series {(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+...} equal to Lnn(this is harmonic series)

Answer (score 1):

1)
...+n/16+n/8 + n/4+ n/n..=? is a geometric series and its sum will always be less than equal 2n. So it is O(n).

2)...+n/5+n/4 + n/3+n/2...n/n..=? is a harmonic series whose sum will be logn.There are mathematical calculations to derive this.So it is O(log n)

Comment: The second one is nlogn